# Is there something like "backdrop-transform" in CSS? Or some way to transform different regions of the same image/video/iframe/etc. independently?

Tags: css, css-houdini

In CSS we have `transform` and `filter`, and we also have `backdrop-filter`. But as far as I can see, we don't have `backdrop-transform`, or anything like it.

To explain what I mean: `backdrop-filter` allows you to filter things that are *behind* the some particular element, so for example you could adjust the hue of a particular region of your background image by positioning a `div` over that region, and then applying `backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(90deg)` to it, like this:

[image: backdrop-filter]

So `backdrop-transform` is the analogue of this for the `transform` property. You could `transform` part of a background image, like this:

[image: backdrop-transform]

You could also do something like this with a **single** embedded youtube video (or any other iframe), for example:

[image: backdrop-transform iframe]

Note that if you tried to use two separate iframes to simulate this, you'd need to somehow keep then in sync with one another (with regard to scrolling, video playback, etc.), which may be hard/impossible if the iframe is cross-domain. This is not to mention the costs of embedding a new iframe/video for every segment that you want to transform.

Maybe I'm too drunk on the amazing promises of Houdini, but I think something like this would be really powerful and very useful (for me, at least!). For example, you could embed a video element, but break it up into quarters, and even jumble those quarters around *using CSS*! Doing it with 4 different masked videos would be tedious and trying to keep them perfectly in sync frame-by-frame might be troublesome (esp. given the low time resolution of the HTML5 video API), and cutting the video up on the server-side just seems unnecessarily arduous.

For my particular use case, I don't even have control over the video (it's in a cross-domain iframe), so CSS is the only way to achieve what I'd like to do. `backdrop-filter` gets me half-way there, but I also need to be able to transform the segments a bit, independently.

---

### Possible Solution #1: `element()`

The CSS [`element(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) can be used anywhere that the `url(..)` function can. It allows you to use a full snapshot (including cross-domain content) of any element on the page as an image (mind-blowing). [Here's a good into](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-element-function) with some demos for those interested. The only problem is that it's only currently supported by Firefox, but it is on a standards track, so it's quite possible that it may be supported by other browsers in the future. If we ever get a cross-browser version of the `element()` function, we could achieve everything that is possible with the hypothetical `backdrop-transform` property. We'd just position a div over the region, then get a live snapshot of it, and transform it as you wish. Performance could be a problem, depending on how `element()` is implemented behind the scenes. [Here is the chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108972) for `element()`.

Comment: The probability of such a feature to ever be part of HTML standard is close to `null`.

Comment: Any thoughts on my edit? Seems like it might already be achievable, at least in Firefox. Any other ideas (hacky or not) are welcome!

Comment: There are several ways to achieve it using current technology, cross browser. But the probability of having it included in HTML Living Standard as a CSS property (named `backdrop-transform` or otherwise) is, again, close to `null`. Which should answer your question. If I misunderstood your question and it's not *"Is there such a feature in CSS?"*, but: *"How can I achieve this?"* your question becomes off-topic for being too broad, not including a live code snippet and not having tried anything towards your goal yet.

Comment: I don't think it becomes off-topic if I ask whether a particular thing is achievable with CSS - especially something as esoteric as this. The title says "Is this sort of **functionality** planned at all?" Which makes it quite clear that I'm not just asking for whether the literal property `backprop-transform` exists, or will exist. I'm asking about functionality. Is there any other way to achieve this with pure CSS?

Comment: To be clear: The reason why all the obvious approaches wouldn't emulate this hypothetical `backdrop-transform`'s functionality is because, as I said in the question, they wouldn't work for a video element (creating 4 videos and trying to keep them in sync frame-by-frame would require a bunch of javascript and probably not be possible due to the time resolution of the HTML5 video element API). So the only solution that I can see so far (performance considerations aside) is the `element()` one, which isn't cross-browser (but *may* be, in the future).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu "There are several ways to achieve it using current technology, cross browser." I am very keen to hear just one of these if you have a moment. If you misunderstood the question, then no worries, but it might be a reminder for you to aim to make comments on questions that aim to clarify and suggest improvements, rather than ones that come across as "proclamations" which aim to dismiss or dismantle it. I would send this in a direct message if it were possible on SO. It seems trifling to point out a lack of friendliness, but I think your comments could do with a bit of that too.

Comment: I'm sorry if my attitude hasn't been great here, but I feel that I've only reflected [your own attitude](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) back at you (which I admit isn't a good thing to do, so I'm actually sorry about that). If you don't want to help, then please, just don't. It's better that way. And even worse, please don't claim to have the solution to my problem and that you're withholding it from me as a "punishment" for my above comments on your behaviour. Anyway, I think that's enough for one comment section.

Comment: (For future reference: It looks like I'm replying to myself there, but that's because a comment by another user was deleted, probably by a moderator. Not that this comment thread is at all useful - would be happy if a mod came through and scrapped it, except for my "To be clear" clarification comment)

Comment: CSS Paint API is unfortunately base on the **2D** canvas API, and transforms are not the strongest point of 2DCanvas... WebGL would have been better for this operation, and to some extents it can actually already be done (at least in Firefox), [using the MediaCapture API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874381/record-browser-tab-with-javascript/50875395#50875395)

Answer (score 0):

You can create this by you own combining different features. Basically you use two elements where inside one you remove a part that you recreate with another element then you can easily apply any kind of transformation.

Here is a basic idea with a *fake* transparency:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin:50px;
  background:
    /*I hide a part of the image using a white gradient*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 50px 50px/100px 100px,
    /*the main image*/
    url(https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  /*I get the same background*/
  background:inherit;
  /*I make the gradient with 0 size*/
  background-size:0 0,auto;
  /*I clip the background to only the content*/
  background-clip:content-box;
  padding:50px 150px 50px 50px;
  /*Apply what you want here*/
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-20deg) skewX(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

The main trick is to have the same background for both and rely on clipping and gradient to simulate the needed effect.

Instead of clipping you can also adjust the background size/position:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin:50px;
  background:
    /*I hide a part of the image using a white gradient*/
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 50px 50px/100px 100px,
    /*the main image*/
    url(https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:inherit;
  background-size:0 0,300px 200px;
  background-position:-50px -50px;
  /*Apply what you want here*/
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-20deg) skewX(15deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

Another idea is to use `clip-path` to have a perfect transparency but it can be a bit tricky to find the different values:

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px;
}

.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 
  50px 100%, 50px 50px, 150px 50px, 150px 150px, 50px 150px, 50px 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1069) -50px -50px/300px 200px no-repeat;

  /*Apply what you want here*/
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-20deg) scale(0.8);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,red);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">

</div>
</div>
```

And to make it easier to handle you can consider CSS variable to easily adjust the region you want to target:

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  margin:5px;
  /*we set background here for inheritance*/
  background-image:var(--img);
  background-size:0 0; /*don't show here*/
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.container:before,
.container:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background-image:inherit;
}
.container:before {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 
  var(--l) 100%, var(--l) var(--t), calc(var(--l) + var(--w)) var(--t), calc(var(--l) + var(--w)) calc(var(--t) + var(--h)), var(--l) calc(var(--t) + var(--h)), var(--l) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
.container:after {
  top:var(--t);
  left:var(--l);
  width:var(--w);
  height:var(--h);
  background-position:calc(-1*var(--l)) calc(-1*var(--t));
  transform:var(--transform,none);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,red);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"
  style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069);
         --t:50px;--l:50px;
         --w:100px;--h:100px;
         --transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-20deg) scale(0.8)">
</div>

<div class="container"
  style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1052);
         --t:10px;--l:50px;
         --w:100px;--h:150px;
         --transform:perspective(100px) rotate(-20deg) scale(0.8)">
</div>
<div class="container"
  style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1055);
         --t:5px;--l:5px;
         --w:80px;--h:80px;
         --transform:perspective(100px) skew(25deg) scale(0.8)">
</div>
<div class="container"
  style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1049);
         --t:100px;--l:100px;
         --w:100px;--h:100px;
         --transform:translate(50px,50px)">
</div>
```

As you can see, the code is reduced to only one container where you can easily set the image, the top/left position of the region and its width/height then the transformation you need to apply.

Comment: OP has asked for a way to take a snapshot of what's currently rendered somewhere and transform it, using CSS. Your answer duplicates the `background` property of two unrelated elements. Which means making a change in the source will not produce a change in the transformed copy.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu `Which means making a change in the source will not produce a change in the transformed copy.`--> the source here is the image which is shared between both elements, so changing it will change both elements (transformed element included) and as you know, the wanted feature doesn't exist so this is an *idea/hack/approximation* or whataver to obtain a similar behavior. Most important, is that when we think about a feature we should try to think about how can achieve it by combining exisiting ones and not try to find it *ready to use* and this is what I tried to do here.

Comment: Some neat examples! I should have been more clear in my question that I've considered duplicating the source, but it doesn't work very well for videos, for example - especially if you wanted to divide it up into, say, 16 regions which are all independently transformed, and keep them in sync, frame-by-frame. +1 though because this, as you said, is an idea/hack/approximation that works in the specific case of background images. Thanks! (I'll edit my question and add a video example)

Comment: @Joe in all the cases the duplicate will be there. Even if there is a feature developed it will rely on duplicating the content behind the scene which is logical even if you will not do it explicitely. Technically, you cannot apply two different transformation to only one element. You are obliged to have different copy and the system will handle the synchronization based on the original element. The question will simply be : " will you do the duplication or will the system do it for you and you will not notice this?". In this answer, I am simply doing the job of a system you want to have ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yep, this makes sense for background images, but have a look at my edit in regards to doing this with a cross-domain iframe, for example (synchronising scroll, or playback in the case of a video, etc.). The `element()` function in Firefox allows us to handle these cases easily, by loading the content just once, and then visually manipulating it - duplicating the pixels, rather than the "content". I think I may have to wait and cross my fingers for a cross-browser `element()` or some other new feature to properly do what I want here. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Joe you didn't get my logic. Using video or image it will be the same. What I meant is that in all the cases you will have a duplicateion of content. In my case I have done this manually by duplicating the image (I can do the same for text, video, etc) but when using `element()` you will not do it explicitely but the browser will do it for your and you will not see this. So *you* will not duplicate the content (which what you want) but inside the implementation the content will for sure get duplicated. I am talking about the logic implementation of such feature, not the use of it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Okay, but duplication at the "pixel level" is different to duplication at the "element level" in some cases, right? E.g. a cross-domain iframe over which you have no control. If the user scrolls down in the iframe, then the [`element()` approach](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-element-function) causes all transformed segments of the iframe to scroll down. Unless I'm mistaken, there's no way to achieve this sort of thing (and many other related things) if you're duplicating the iframe itself - you'd need to be able to watch the scroll position and update all the duplicate iframes.

Comment: @Joe we are talking about two different things :) I am not talking about the use of such thing. I am talking about what is happening in the implementation. If you work for Google Chrome and you have to develop such feature, how you will do it? the user will not duplicate the content BUT you as a developer of that feature you will have a duplication somewhere. You will read the information of that `element()` and inside the code you will create two element and you will create a code that will make those two element remain the same. Again it's not about CSS level and using, it's about logic

Comment: @Joe `if you're duplicating the iframe itself - you'd need to be able to watch the scroll position and update all the duplicate iframes.` --> you will not to do it yourself but the browser will do it for you and the browser will watch the scroll and update everything for you. You will do nothing because the developer have made it easy for you. Exactly the idea behind my code. If you use my code, you have to set the image only once and my code will duplicate this for ... I hope you get my point now

Comment: @Temani, Houdini is all about tapping into the JavaScript behind CSS. At least in principle, what OP asks for is possible using Houdini. The browser would be instructed at render level to use the exact same source (an element in the page) for 4 different other elements that could be placed independently in the page. In principle, it's possible. What happens in source element happens, in real time, in the rest. Houdini smears the concept of "CSS only", as it uses low level JavaScript, to influence the CSS output. An example of such a worklet is, to my understanding, what this question is about.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think I got your point originally. My point is only that your solution (very plain and simply) won't work for a cross-domain iframe (for example). This is just an example showing how your solution doesn't solve the problem *in general*. I specifically require a solution that works in all cases, including the cross-domain iframe one, just as can be achieved with `element()`. Like I said earlier though, I appreciate the solution for the special case of an image/video/etc. over which the developer has control, as I'm sure other people may find that helpful.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu and in all the cases and whataver the level will be, we will have duplication. That's what I am trying to explain. In my example the duplication was done in the CSS level by *me* so a user that will not see the CSS will not see this duplication. It can be done at a JS level, so nothing will be seen on the CSS or the HTML but if you dig into the JS code you may see this. It can also be done at browser level where you will see nothing unless you check the source code, etc. My point is that such thing will for sure need a duplication whataver the level will be.

Comment: Well, the main difference is that: when you duplicate an element (or, should I say, the rendering layer of an element) and that element has a hiccup or an error, all the *n* copies will be in sync. They will display the same thing: the error, the hiccup, the anomaly, because the source is the same exact thing and they are just copies of the rendered layer. If you simply use the same external source, you run the risk of them being out of sync. And it's quite **a big difference**, in terms of user experience.

Comment: @Joe yes it's clear that my solution is only a particular case, we aren't debating on this but based on that we can think of implementing this feature for more generic content based on the *duplication* but it can be hidden to user. So no need to wait for a ready feature. You can write your own code that will do the duplication and your own code that will make sure we will have the synchronization of the data ;) since such feature will not be avaible in the near future

Comment: @TemaniAfif But how could that be possible with a cross-domain iframe, for example? We can't access the state (e.g. scroll position) within the iframe, so we can't write our own code to handle the synchronisation, right?